# How do I tell what's going wrong in the Unity build process?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been using Unity for a while now, but I haven't seen something like this yet. I think it might be because I switched to Linux a few months ago, I'm not sure. But Unity's giving me errors when it builds, and not telling me anything about it! (Except for that its not running properly...)

I'm trying to build an update for [Kettle3D](https://kettle3d.github.io/), a game we're making, and the output it's giving me is this:

```
Exception: /home/kettle/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.3.15f1/Editor/Data/il2cpp/build/deploy/net471/il2cpp.exe did not run properly!
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:128)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo) (at /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:71)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.RunIl2CppWithArguments (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] arguments, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo, System.String workingDirectory) (at /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:519)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp (UnityEditor.Il2Cpp.Il2CppBuildPipelineData data, System.String outputDirectory, System.String workingDirectory, System.Boolean platformSupportsManagedDebugging) (at /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:500)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () (at /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:337)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String stagingAreaData, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action`1[T] modifyOutputBeforeCompile, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry) (at /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:72)
DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.SetupStagingArea (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[T] filesToNotOverwrite) (at /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.cs:223)
DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.cs:42)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.cs:60)
UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Modules/DefaultBuildPostprocessor.cs:27)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:340)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun() (at /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindow.cs:136)
```

It's obvious it didn't build properly, otherwise it wouldn't be giving me these errors!

I don't know what's going on here, all I know is that its stopping me from doing anything and any help would be much appreciated.

I will try this on Windows and see if that changes it.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot give you a direct answer but I can give you tips on how to find the issue, or where to look for it. This will take a lot of work but I cannot help you more without any more context to this error.

Go back using the repository, commit after commit, and see which one finally would work (or go from the latest working version upwards). Then compare changes and look for anything suspicious. In order from ones with the biggest potential eg:

- Reflection
- Generic methods
- Generic classes
- Native invocation
- Cross platform code
- Preprocessor
- New Plugins/DLLs
- Unusual meta data

Those might give IL compiler hard time and in result throw this error.

If you do not have a repository, make one right now! And using your memory reverse all changes that you made that could cause this issue and make a commit every time you changed something without compilation error (not build, just in Unity)!

Comment: Okay, thank you for that. I've looked at the commit history, and the last place it worked was right before I switched from Mono to IL2CPP.

Comment: I ended up switching back to Mono again. Turns out it wasn't the scripting system that was causing a change in speed, it was the lighting engine. Deleting it helped.